# Convert timestamp from database to user's local time

Tags: javascript

I have a chat application, and I need to **display user's time.**

i save message `time();` in PHP into database.

if I use javascript `Date();` this will display user's computer's time

how to **convert timestamp to user's time**

ex.if user type a message

hi there! **(1981169841) timestamp**

hi there **07:30pm 20013-07-30 (user's time, not server's time)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) constructor accepts unix timestamp(in *milliseconds*) as parameter.

Comment: i tried var d = new Date(<?PHP echo time();?>); and it print out different time, 1970...